# I'm using the Bitrix24 api generator to export my data but can't seem to filter the response by the array position[]

Tags: arrays, api, etl, crm, bitrix

Bitrix only brings up to 50 positions in the array list of all my data, this happens because of a security matter and, for what I've seen, can't be changed. So, to export the data from Bitrix to my dataware house (currently going through tranformation inside Pentaho) i need to get something near 50.000 arrays (keep in mind I can only get 50 at a time!!!! + they come at a non-organized id order) I need help to filter the ids in a order so my requests become easier. These are my parameters:

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sERy3.png)

If anyone know what kind of selection or filter I could use I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the query from the window shown in your picture (from the developer resources templates if the picture goes offline in the future) and look at the formatted result.

For most Bitrix24 API requests the response, which had 10 results in this example, will be in the format:

```
Array
   (
      [result] => Array
      (
         [0] => Array()
         [1] => Array()
         .....
         [9] => Array()

      [total] => 10
      [time] => Array()
)
```

However, when there are 50+ results, it looks like this:

```
Array
   (
      [result] => Array
      (
         [0] => Array()
         [1] => Array()
         .....
         [49] => Array()

      [next] => 50
      [total] => 12345
      [time] => Array()
)
```

The addition of the [next] item is key, as you can sent the request again with the additional parameter start with the value from next. For a URL query string this would be equivalent to putting &start=50 on the end of it. Put it in a loop to run while there is a [next] returned and set start to the value of next on each iteration to get all of the results.

I found some old code as an example. I believe this used Guzzle (PHP) but it should be adaptable to whatever you'd like rather easily. The comments for the code flow are more important than the code itself.

```
do { //Need to run it at least once to determine if there is a 'next' or not
    $params = [
      'query' =>  
      [ 'order' => 
        [
          'ID' => 'ASC',
        ],
      'filter' => 
        [
           //you could put the DATE_CREATE filter here but it sounds like you may not want it. 
        ],
      'select' => 
        [
          'NAME',
          'LAST_NAME',
          'STATUS_ID',
          'EMAIL'
        ],
      'start' => [(isset($data['next']))? $data['next'] : 0], //in other words, if there is a 'next' in the response data, set start to the value of 'next'. If not (the first run) start at 0
]
     ]; 
  $response = $client->request('POST','crm.contact.list',$params); // Send a POST request using crm.contact.list with the parameters above
  $data = $response->getBody(); //get the response
  $data = json_decode($data, true); //decode the response
} while ($data['next']); //keep going while 'next' is returned. Remember, once there are less than 50, it won't be and you'll have it all.
```

I'm not sure if you're still in this situation, but it was certainly something I stumbled with when I started using the API so hopefully this answer can benefit you or somebody in the future.